# Android button onClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onclicklistener

I am trying to open new `Activity` by clicking on a button in my `OnClickListener` method. How does `OnClickListener` method work and what should be done in it to start a new `Activity`?

Comment: Intent intent= new Intent(this, NewActivit.class); startactivity(intent);

Comment: pleae do some research before putting your question here

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This task can be accomplished using one of the android's main building block named as Intents and One of the methods `public void startActivity (Intent intent)` which belongs to your Activity class.

An intent is an abstract description of an operation to be performed. It can be used with startActivity to launch an Activity, broadcastIntent to send it to any interested BroadcastReceiver components, and startService(Intent) or bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int) to communicate with a background Service.

An Intent provides a facility for performing late runtime binding between the code in different applications. Its most significant use is in the launching of activities, where it can be thought of as the glue between activities. It is basically a passive data structure holding an abstract description of an action to be performed.

Refer the official docs -- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

`public void startActivity (Intent intent)` -- Used to launch a new activity.

So suppose you have two Activity class --

1. **PresentActivity** -- This is your current activity from which you want to go the second activity.
2. **NextActivity** -- This is your next Activity on which you want to move.

So the Intent would be like this

```
Intent(PresentActivity.this, NextActivity.class)
```

Finally this will be the complete code

```
public class PresentActivity extends Activity {
  protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
              // Perform action on click   
              Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(PresentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);

              // currentContext.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);

              PresentActivity.this.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);
            }
          });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

```
//create a variable that contain your button
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        //On click function
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Create the intent to start another activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), AnotherActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `OnClicklistener` or you can use `android:onClick="myMethod"` in your button's **xml** code from which you going to open a new layout. So when that button is clicked your **myMethod** function will be called automatically. Your `myMethod` function in class look like this.

```
public void myMethod(View v) {
Intent intent=new Intent(context,SecondActivty.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

And in that **SecondActivity.class** set new layout in contentview.

Comment: How does java/xml know which method from which class it is?

Comment: Layout file will map in setContentView

Answer (score 3):

easy:

launching activity (onclick handler)

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
 myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
 CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

on the new activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Intent intent = getIntent();
String value = intent.getStringExtra("key"); //if it's a string you stored.
```

and add your new activity in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="NextActivity"/>
```