# Android Error while trying to start an activity on button click

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a problem with the method public void onClick(View v),
I tried to implement a Button that starts another activity.

```
startgpsactivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GPSbutton);
startgpsactivity.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent inent = new Intent(this, GPS.class);
    startActivity(inent);
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Post your logcat

Comment: it doesn t run at all in eclipse it marks mee a redpoint with a cross in it where it is written multiple marks at this line.

Answer (score 3):

Try this way

```
startgpsactivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GPSbutton);

startgpsactivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent inent = new Intent(your_Activity.this, GPS.class);
    startActivity(inent);
});
```

For more details go to http://www.howtosolvenow.com/2013/11/android-button-setonclicklistener-example/

Answer (score 2):

Write the code properly,

```
startgpsactivity.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent inent = new Intent(this, GPS.class);

    startActivity(inent);
});
```

similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636752/android-button-onclicklistener).