# startActivity in onclick

Tags: android, oncreate, start-activity

have a simple Activity with a onClick method - it works
but Android Studio marks startActivity red says cannot resolve method - so why?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lyt_start);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btn1:

            Intent int_Update = new Intent(v.getContext(), aty_Update.class);

            startActivity(int_Update);

            break;

        case R.id.btn2:

            Intent int_Start = new Intent(v.getContext(), aty_Main.class);
            startActivity(int_Start);

            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure, this class `extends Activity`?

Comment: if startActivity is underlined red that means you project isn't configured correctly or building correctly. nothing is wrong with the code. Try to do a gradle sync, and i bet it will show you some errors or something.

Comment: Hey you are my man - you're right - after doing it ... all errors are gone - it's magic - no ist Shemesh ;))

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `v.getContext()`, use:

```
Intent int_Update = new Intent(this, aty_Update.class);
```

Or `MyActivity.this` instead.

Also, you're not setting a `onClickListener` correctly. Take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636752/android-button-onclicklistener) to learn how to do it properly.

Comment: I've done "this" before but Studio marks it red - error cannot resolve constructor

Comment: have u used `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: >Or `MyActivity.this` instead.< just replace with your activity name.

Comment: You've replaced MyActivity with your activity's name? Man, did you change the way you tried to implement the onClick? Your way is wrong.

Comment: sure I replaced it

Comment: used it like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464100/starting-intent-from-onclicklistener

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lyt_start);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btn1:

            activityStarter(aty_Update.class);

            break;

        case R.id.btn2:

            activityStarter(aty_Main.class);

            break;
}


       Intent int_Update;

public void activityStarter(Class<?> cls){
        int_Update = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), cls);
        startActivity(int_Update);
    }
```

Comment: activity starter app Inventor?

Comment: what error does it show in the app and android studio